# Target Audiences in List View display as GUIDs

Tags: list, list-view, audiences

In SharePoint 2010, I have a standard Announcements list on which I have enabled Audience Targeting. When a list view is setup to display the Target Audience, it renders as a GUID, not as the display name of the Audience. Has anyone been able to fix this?

Comment: Update: I've just found that _some_ list items _do_ display the display name of the audience. In fact, I have an example with a list containing 5 list items. If I set the audience for 4 of these to the same value, they all display the audience name fine. However, when I set the last list item to the same audience, they all display GUIDs. Really weird.

Comment: Update: It seems that setting the audience for the most recent list items causes this behaviour. I can successfully set the target audience for older items (>2 days old). But I if try to set target audience for the more recent items, all list items' audience column display as GUIDs.

Comment: did you ever get a definite solution to this problem? I now have the same issue in a SP2010 environment (no update from SP2007).
We are already on SP1 + CUdec2011 Would love to get an answer.

Comment: No, my status is the same. As Lisa points out below, the workaround is to avoid targeting the first item in the view. We are on SP1 now, but I have not had the chance to test this again. Sounds like you did, with no luck, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've experienced the same thing... I've noticed that it only happens when the first item on the list or library is targeted.

I had a list where item # 1 had no targeting and a few others did. It all looked fine until I targeted the first item and then all the items got messed up. I removed the targeting on the first item and all went back to normal.

I then experimented some more: I targeted an item further down the list, leaving the first one untargeted and everything was ok, but then I sorted the list by modified (instead of name) and hey presto... GUIDs again!!

So basically, targeting the first item on the list is what messes things up!

Comment: Thanks, Lisa. You're absolutely right. In my setup, targeting the first list item also messes up the display. 
We're not on SP1 yet. Don't know whether this is something that SP1 fixes.
(marked as answer, since this is as close as we can get, IMO).

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this when audience rules were based on distribution lists rather than "real" compiled audience rules

Comment: Ok, thanks, but it is a compiled audience. It's a single audience that includes all users from our AD. I think I'll try to add another audience, based on a specific AD property, assign this for some list items, and see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

Is the database from 2007 that was upgraded using the db attach method?  If so you need to update the SSP database when creating the User Profile service to import the Audience from 2007. [More info here](https://web.archive.org/web/20151110221048/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/alimaz/archive/2009/11/08/upgrading-moss-2007-ssp-user-profiles-and-mysite-content-to-sharepoint-server-2010-using-db-attach-method.aspx).

Comment: No, we have not upgraded from 2007. The audience I'm using here was setup from scratch and compiled succesfully with 298 members currently.

Answer (score 0):

The GUID display on audiences is by design. 
I have also had the same problem where the first item in the list is displayed as  GUID - I even tried different lists..

There is a link here http://www.vishansondhi.com/?p=36 which confirms that is an issue which Microsoft have not fixed (& I believe they don't intend to either)