# How to filter blog posts on the blog site home page according to target audiences?

Tags: sharepoint-server, blog, audience-targeting, audiences

I want to display only the blog posts which belong to a specific audience in the blog sites Default.aspx page .Currently i enabled audience targeting on the posts list and my blog items are assigned different audiences but all the items are displayed on the blog home page. How do I filter the posts on the homepage(default.aspx) according to audiences?

Thanks!

**Edit 1** Target Audiences column in the list view

[image]

**Edit 2** Target Audiences with name in view

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you Create a View where Filter will have a value as Assigned to or related to [Me]. Then call this view in default.aspx page.

Comment: I don't have a Column AssignedTo or RelatedTo. I have a column called Target Audiences which contains GUIDs

Comment: Assigned to or related was just examples. IS there any column which is capturing the users which are suppose to see their blogs. Check in view, if there is any column which you can add and then in filter you can have this column as [Me]

Comment: No. I don't think so. I only have that Target Audiences Column which contain GUIDs. Could that be of any help ?

Comment: Target Audience is generally a people picker field. How it can have  guids?

Comment: Can you please take a look at the image i have posted

Comment: please go through this link and try to remove the guids from target audience
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12238/target-audiences-in-list-view-display-as-guids

Comment: Ok I did what the accepted answer says. It is not a complete fix but other answers do say that it an issue in SharePoint. I got Audience name in that column for now. How should I filter based on the audience of the logged in user?

Comment: Now click on Modify View in the ribbon and select Target Audience in the Filter as Show Items only when Target Audience equals [Me]. This will show only those items where the login user is the target audience. Then you can add this view in the default.aspx page by adding list view web part

Comment: I changed the view of the Posts webpart on the Blog site home page. Now i get no blogs to display message. The filter rule I gave is Target Audiences "Contains" [Me] . I could not set equals. It showed an alert message that equals could not be set for this field

Comment: can you check the type of target Audience column in Library setting

Comment: The type of the column is "Audience Targeting"